# Reg Party Field List - delimitter and icons not showing up

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am using CRM 2013 with latest SP and Roll-ups. I face a problem which am not sure if someone already resolved it.

After the page load, my party field in the meetings seems to loose the separators and icons (that seems to show up while loading but refreshes after loading). Please see the images below. Does any one know what causes this ?

[image: Seems correct while loading with separators and icons]

[image: After loading, becomes a single field with no separators]

[image]

Comment: Tried on a sort-of-vanilla 2013 (I can't remember if and which rollups are installed) I have here, seems to work properly. Have you already made sure that no customizations are involved with the form ?

Comment: Thanks, if the OOB feature looks alright, then it is some customization that is interferring I believe. I imported all the attendes from a SQL DB, perhaps, something wrong with my import then. Will post an answer as I find it.